# Why does not work nested routes in react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I try to use nested routes in react application, but I receive 404 page. Please help.
First of all, I tried to use two dynamic nested routes and it didn't work. Next, I replace the first dynamic route to static, but all the same, it didn't work correctly.

App.jsx...

```
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { About } from './components/About';
import { NotFound } from './components/404';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
           <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about" exact>
          <About />
        </Route>
        <Route component={NotFound} path={"*"} exact />
      </Switch> 
    </BrowserRouter> 
  );
}
```

About.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Nested from './Nested';
import Switch from 'react-router/Switch';

const About = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to={`${props.match.url}/id`}>Nested</Link>
        <Route path={`${props.match.url}/id`} component={Nested} />
        </div>
    )
}

const AboutWithRouter = withRouter(About)

export { AboutWithRouter as About }
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to passs your components as a `<Route />` param, like `<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />`?

Comment: Don't I do it????

Comment: From `<Route path="/" exact><Home /></Route><Route path="/about" exact><About /></Route>` part of your code, it looks like you don't

Comment: try to wrap `Route` in `Switch` in About.jsx, and /id should be /:id if it is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include path="*" on the NotFound Route. Omitting path will cause the Route to always match.

```
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use children elements in Route, use `<Route component>`.It will be rendered with route props.

```
<Route path="/about"  component={About} />
```

[temporary codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-routes-j82hj)